# Как избавиться от вложенности Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, файловая-система, рефакторинг

Как можно переписать код без такого количества вложений?

```
filenames = []
trees = []
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.py'):
            filenames.append(os.path.join(dirname, file))
            if len(filenames) == 100:
                break
```

Comment: Меня беспокоит `if len(filenames) == 100:` у вас он точно в том месте находится? :) просто, текущая реализация позволит в filenames больше 100 элементов добавить, т.к. сначала элемент добавляется, а потом проверяется. У меня ваш код заполнил filenames на несколько сотен элементов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На одну вложенность меньше:

```
filenames = []

for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if not file.endswith('.py'):
            continue
        
        # Если нужно строго 100 файлов найти
        if len(filenames) == 100:
            break
  
        filenames.append(os.path.join(dirname, file))

print(len(filenames), filenames)
```

---

Через `glob` в одну строку:

```
import glob
filenames = [file_name for file_name in glob.glob(path + '/**/*.py', recursive=True)[:100]]
```

если нужна эффективность (`glob` сначала найдет все файлы, а после вернет их список), тогда используем итератор:

```
filenames = []
for file_name in glob.iglob(path + '/**/*.py', recursive=True):
    if len(filenames) == 100:
        break

    filenames.append(file_name)
```

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с использованием генератора быстрее и использует меньше памяти

```
from itertools import islice

filenames = list(islice((i for _, _, fs in os.walk('.', topdown=True)
                         for i in fs if i.endswith('.py')), 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант ещё можно попробовать выделить части кода в отдельные функции, если хотим бороться с вложенностью

```
filenames = []
trees = []

def process_files(files):
  for file in files:
    if not process_file(file):
      break 

def process_file(file):
  if file.endswith('.py'):
    filenames.append(os.path.join(dirname, file))
    return len(filenames) == 100
  return True

for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
  process_files(files)
```

Comment: Глобальные переменные -- зло. Лучше передавать в process_file список filenames