# Поиск строки в файле

Tags: python

Есть задача: нужно отыскать файл в формате sql среди десятков други.
Например у нас есть директория на гитхаб с большим количеством данных 
Программа ожидает строку, которую будет искать (input()).
После того, как строка введена, программа ищет её во всех файлах, выводит имена найденных файлов построчно и выводит количество найденных файлов.
Программа снова ожидает ввод, но теперь поиск происходит только среди отобранных на предыдущем этапе файлов.
Программа снова ожидает ввод.
...

Пока все на что меня хватило:

```
import os

migrations = 'Migrations'
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    (input('Введите строку: INSERT'))
```

Comment: Попробуйте поиск файлов по формату через glob сделать, вот пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/860959/201445

Comment: Извините мне не совсем понятно.

Comment: Показал пример поиска файлов. Это одна из задач, которую нужно будет вам решить